# How do I force a display resolution on load with Debian Wheezy?

Tags: grub2

I tried adding vga=773 to /boot/grub/grub.cfg on the same like as the kernel is invoked, but it still loaded up in 1600x1200 which puts my ipKVM out of sync.

Answer (score 2):

"grub.cfg" should be grub2 (legacy grub used grub.conf), which would use gfxpayload= instead of vga=.

*e.g.* try

**gfxpayload=1600x1200**

or

**gfxpayload=auto**

('auto' should use the LCD's native resolution).
But beware... you're not supposed to edit grub.cfg directly, because its changes will be overwritten.

[GRUB 2 manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html)